# A method to search questions on more than one criteria (not tag)

Tags: support, questions, search

Quick basic question.

Is there a method to search questions on more than one criteria?

**example**, oldest, unanswered, with zero answers (as opposed to >0 answers, but no accepted answer)?

***Where is, or how do we find the way to modify our search criteria***

***nb this is not about tags as such***

*I do not need a solution for the example*

Comment: Search for `answers:0`?

Comment: I needed a list, found it.. this is just an example

Comment: @hims056 I DO NOT DOUBT it's a dupe.. but finding the info is difficult  so close it and link it to appropriate question and maybe people will find these things more easily..

Comment: @Skippy Recently introduced Help Center (which is itself a few months old now) shows **[How do I search?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)** link. Which contains all the **Advanced Search Options**. Also, on the search results page, **Advanced Search Tips** link is also displayed. I believe Stack Exchange has tried its best so that users can find these options easily and I think this info is not at all difficult to find. The edits you made clarified the question. Thanks and Good luck

Comment: @Skippy: Settle down. Why are you so frustrated? Your question was originally unclear and it caused confusion. So what? You edited and clarified. Move on. The system worked.

Comment: @AzizShaikh recently introduced help center.. sorry I didn't ralise it had changed. so I didn't think to go back to it. I'm tired. every time I o=post here I get a downvote. the question in and of itself was not bad. it would've been a good signpost for others. never mind I'm over it. I can't handle it. Even my best voted posts here and on SO get people creeping around and downvoting them. It's a fking jk. I'm TIRED of it. I am volunteering also. sorry I dont play the game and dont fit in with the club here..

Comment: @animuson see my comment above. this site is hard for users to try and participate on, if they are not popular. It shouldn't be based on personality, and the ability to fit in with a bunch of users who have been here since time began.

Comment: @animuson the original question was clear. I gave an example to illustrate what I was ansking. Bt as usual people swoop in and don't read it. drives me crazy

Comment: I just want to close this account. nothing good ever comes of me participating here. I mean here on SO Meta.. some other SE sites appreciate my conributions

Comment: @Skippy: Just because it's clear to you in your mind doesn't mean it's clear to everyone else. When I talk about programming with my friends, everything I say is crystal clear and makes sense to me, but they are often in the dark wondering what I'm talking about. People naturally read and understand things differently. Explaining things clearly is the best way to get your point across. -- If you're really dead-set on deleting your account, [follow these instructions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a method to search questions on more than one criteria?

Yes. There are many operators we can use for advanced search. For full list of operators see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the answer:

go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

click on advanced search tips.

[image: adv search][image: tips]

Answer (score 1):

[Search with answers:0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0), click on **newest** tab and go to the last page.